# Как сохранить состояние меню?

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Имеется невидимая группа элементов меню:

```
<group  android:id="@+id/groupBookmarks"
        android:visible="false">

        <item android:id="@+id/bookmark1"
            android:title="@string/rings"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>
</group>
```

Во время выполнения программы, при определенных условиях, делаю группу видимой:

```
navMenu.setGroupVisible(R.id.groupBookmarks, true);
```

Но при перезапуске приложения меню инфлейтится заново и возвращается к невидимому состоянию.
Знаю про preferences, но не понимаю как этим пользоваться для моих нужд.
Как я могу реализовать сохранение видимого состояния меню?

Comment: вы должны будете из preference считывать одно поле типа boolean и в зависимости от его значения показывать или скрывать значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы создал отдельный класс для работы с префами:

```
public class Preferences {

    private final static String VISIBILITY_FLAG = "is_visible";

    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    public Preferences(Context context) {
        mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setVisibilityFlag(boolean isVisible) {
        getEditor().putBoolean(VISIBILITY_FLAG, isVisible).commit();
    }

    public boolean getVisibilityFlag() {
        return mPreferences.getBoolean(FLAG, false);
    }

    private SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor() {
        return mPreferences.edit();
    }
}
```

После чего в активити я бы создал переменную, например (если вы знаете что такое MVP или другие архитектурные паттерны то работал бы через презентер)

```
private boolean isVisible;
private Preferences preferences = new Preferences(context);
```

И далее при изменении состояния я передавал бы значание isVisible в префы:

```
preferences.setVisibilityFlag(isVisible);
```

И соответственно при загрузке приложения получял бы их:

```
isVisible = preferences.getVisibilityFlag();
```

Вот здесь можно рассмотреть более подробно 
https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html